# JSOM - Cannot get property "executeFunc" of undefined

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom

My project is SharePoint-Hosted Add-in and i want to verify if script sp.js is loadded before run my code in App.js file.

**When i use**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', pageLoad);
});
```

**I have load this js files:**

```
  <!-- Required references to use the JSOM from a SharePoint-hosted html page -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../_layouts/15/sp.ui.controls.js"></script>
```

When i insert 
SP.SOD.executeFunc worked, bu pageload, refreshed **two** times...

**Error is:**
[image]

> Tommorow when i uses Promise.then or .done in [**this post**](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203851/sp-online-use-promises-in-sharepoint-hosted-add-in) error is the same :
>
> > jQuery.Deferred exception: Unable to get property '**then**' of
> >     undefined or null reference TypeError

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have below js files loaded in exact sequence.

```
<script src="/_layouts/1033/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.runtime.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: see my updated question, i doest have sp.core.js and init.js

Comment: <script src="../_layouts/15/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script> pageLoad func reloaded 2 times, 2 times says : "pageLoad is loadded" in my picture